# UIImageView inside UITableViewCell does not get updated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am creating a custom `UITableViewCell` to include an `UIImageView` and some related text. I am getting the images from the Internet and while the images load, I display a temporary `UIImage`.

I am using a separate thread to get the `UIImage`. Once an `UIImage` is downloaded, I am firing a method on the main thread to set the image in the `UIImageView` (getting the instance of `UIImageView` using tags)

But whatever I do, the images are not changed. The cells still display older images (corresponding to different row - due to reusing of cells) and new images are not reflected. Log statements show that the method to set the image is being called.

I even tried changing the image to a static image in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`
 but even then the image does not change.

*Edit*
I tried calling `reloadData` on the `UITableView` after changing the `UIImage`, but the `UIImage` still does not change.

Here's the relevant piece of code

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
        image = [imagesArray valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row]];
        if(image == nil){
            //display temporary images. When scrolling stops, detach new thread to get images for rows visible
            NSString *pth = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"folder" ofType:@"png"];
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pth];
            [imgView setImage:image];
        }
        else{
            [imgView setImage:image];
        }
```

**Method which is called on the main thread after an image is downloaded**

```
-(void)setImageInArray:(NSIndexPath *)indPath{
    [filesTable reloadData];
}
```

In the thread, I am adding the `UIImage` object to `imagesArray`. So when the next time the `cellForRowAtIndex` method is called on `reloadData`, the new `UIImage` should be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UITableView's cells are cached, so modifying the cell after it has been rendered will have no effect. Try sending the table a `reloadData` message, after updating the UIImageView.